# How to get table from nested table [PL/SQL]

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, nested-table

I want get table from nested table.

Create table type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Name_list_t AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50)
```

Alter my table adding column nested table:

```
ALTER TABLE MOVIES ADD Movi_name_list Name_list_t NESTED TABLE Movi_name_list STORE AS Movi_name_list
```

Add table to nested table:

```
Declare
extractNames Name_list_t;
Begin
(...) some code...
update movies set movi_name_list=extractNames where movi_id=id_movie;
End;
```

Inserting table work great. Finally, I want get table from nested table and I don't know how. I try two ways but no successful:

```
select movi_name_list into extractNames from movies where movi_id=1; 
extractNames := select movi_name_list from movies;
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The first SELECT should work. What error are you getting?

Comment: `select column_value bulk collect into extractNames from table(select movi_name_list from movies where movi_id=1)`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff You don't have to do it like this, you can just select the nested table into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Select from [@Egor Skriptunoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1847592/egor-skriptunoff) work!

Solution:

```
select column_value bulk collect into extractNames from table(select movi_name_list from movies where movi_id=1)
```

My select cast incorrectly, I guess.